# PHP Goutte / CURL - get content of aspx pages

Tags: php, asp.net, curl, web-crawler, goutte

I'm trying to get data from here: https://nen.nipez.cz/SeznamZadavacichPostupu

I already solved problem to get this first page content but i'm not able to get content from any of next pages.

I already tried to submit form but i think i miss some values in form data and i really dont know how and which specific data should i send.

```php
        $client = new Client();
        $client->setHeader('Referer', 'https://nen.nipez.cz/SeznamZadavacichPostupu');

        $pageContent = $client->request("GET", 'https://nen.nipez.cz/SeznamZadavacichPostupu');
        $form = $pageContent->selectButton('Další stránka')->form();

        $contentOfNextPage = $client->submit($form);
```